# Clone user profile

Tags: configuration, settings, clipboard, user-profile, users

Is there any reasonable way to copy user profile with all settings (Firefox, Thunderbird, Netbeans, git, fonts etc.) to have it as a base for another profile, so I didn't have to set up everything from the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `/etc/skel` you’ll find the files that a new user will automatically have in their home directory. You can copy everything you find worthwhile there.